# Tests do not timeout in Mocha

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6, mocha.js

I can't seem to set a timeout for any of my tests from a test file in Mocha:

### test/test.js

```
import request from 'supertest';
import app from '../app';

import { resetDB } from './helpers';
import { config } from '../app/config';
import { testHost } from '../config';

before(function() {
  this.timeout(10000);
  return resetDB();
});

describe('/myroute', function() {
  this.timeout(10000);
  it('should respond', function(done) {
    this.timeout(10000);
    request(app)
        .get('/recommendations')
        .query({ query: 'somevalue' })
        .end(function(err, res) {
            console.log('res is', res.body);
            if (err) {
                done(err);
            } else {
                done();
            }
        });
  });
});
```

When I execute my `npm run test` script in package.json:

```
"test": "NODE_ENV=test ./node_modules/mocha/bin/mocha test/test --compilers js:babel-core/register",...
```

The tests run immediately, nowhere close to 10000 ms. Why?

Comment: Are you trying to *create* an arbitrary delay in your tests? `this.timeout` increases the maximum time before a test automatically ends due to a timeout, unless I've misunderstood.

Comment: Oh right, yeah I'm trying to create a delay, so maybe I should just use a `setTimeout`

Comment: Can you're explain how do you expect the code above to work? What is each of these timeouts supposed to be for?

Comment: I just wanted to delay the execution of the tests. The background for why I'm doing this is that I'm getting this strange behavior where it seems like only SOME of my seed data (from `before` in resetDB) is there by the time my tests are run. I wanted to see if delaying the execution will make it work. I used `setTimeout` and it hasn't solved my problem. When I run the tests again without resetting the database, the tests pass fine. I'm using an Elasticsearch DB.